# Convert @Query MonetaryAmount result

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-money

I just converted all of my `java.math.BigDecimal` usages to `javax.money.MonetaryAmount` (where they represented money). I am currently "assuming" the currency to be USD with the help of a `MoneyUtils` to avoid adding extra database columns that will only contain "USD" in them. This can be seen in the next 2 snippets.

```java
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MonetaryAmountConverter
        implements AttributeConverter<MonetaryAmount, BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal convertToDatabaseColumn(final MonetaryAmount monetaryAmount) {
        return DefaultUtils.defaultOrNull(
                monetaryAmount,
                ma -> ma.getNumber().numberValue(BigDecimal.class));
    }

    @Override
    public MonetaryAmount convertToEntityAttribute(final BigDecimal monetaryAmountValue) {
        if (monetaryAmountValue == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return MoneyUtils.of(monetaryAmountValue);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public final class MoneyUtils {
    public static final CurrencyUnit DOLLAR = Monetary.getCurrency(Locale.US);
    public static MonetaryAmount of(@NonNull final BigDecimal value) {
        return Money.of(value, MoneyUtils.DOLLAR);
    }
}
```

I have this `@Repository` method that should give me a sum, which could be `null` if no rows match:

```java
@Query("query that can return null or a numeric")
MonetaryAmount sumSomeData();
```

The problem is that it doesn't go through my `MonetaryAmountConverter`. I tried adding a `@Convert` directly to the method but it didn't work.

```java
@Query("query that can return null or a numeric")
@Convert(converter = MonetaryAmountConverter.class)
MonetaryAmount sumSomeData();
```

So it appears that an `AttributeConverter` with `@Converter(autoApply = true)` applies to JPA Entity fields, but not to method return types, even when `@Convert` is added to the method signature.

- Is there something I am missing?
- Is there a way to do this without needing to do the conversion manually in the caller of this repository method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [constructor expression](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#ql-select-clause):

> The SELECT clause identifies which objects and values to return as the query results. The expressions discussed in [Section 11.4, “Expressions”](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#ql-expressions) are all valid select expressions, except where otherwise noted. See the section [Section 11.10, “Query API”](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#ql-api) for information on handling the results depending on the types of values specified in the SELECT clause.
>
> There is a particular expression type that is only valid in the select clause. Hibernate calls this “dynamic instantiation”. JPQL supports some of that feature and calls it a “constructor expression”

General example:

```sql
select new Person(user.name, address)
from User as user
left join user.address as address
```

Before you ask, no, you cannot call methods, only constructors. Also, you'll need to consider the fact that your query may return `null`. You could write a wrapper class.

```java
public final class MonetaryAmountWrapper {
  public MonetaryAmountWrapper(final BigDecimal value) {
    this.monetaryAmount = Money.of(value, MoneyUtils.DOLLAR);
  }

  private final MonetaryAmount monetaryAmount;
}
```